# How can a JPanel be changed after added to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have created a subclass of JPanel to display images. I instantiate this in the constructor of a JFrame and add it to that JFrame. This works perfectly. Then I have added a button with an ActionListener to change that Image. My problem is that the JFrame won´t update although I have tried repainting etc.

The subclass of JPanel:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage bf;
    public ImagePanel(String dateiname)
    {
        try {
            bf = ImageIO.read(new File(dateiname));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(bf.getScaledInstance(300,200,1),0,0,null );
    }
}
```

The JFrame is basically this

```
public class Hauptfenster extends JFrame {

private JButton changeImage;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private ImagePanel ip;


public Hauptfenster {

ip = new ImagePanel("first_image.jpg");

buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(changeImage);

changeImage.addActionListener((e) -> {

ip = new ImagePanel("new_image.jpg");
ip.setVisible(true);


});


this.add(buttonPanel);
this.add(ip);
this.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Why doesn´t the method in the ActionListener update the ip component in the JFrame Hauptfenster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `ip = new ImagePanel("new_image.jpg");` you're creating a whole new ImagePanel that has nothing to do with your current layout. You could.

```
remove(ip);
ip = new ImagePanel("new_image.jpg");
add(ip);
repaint();
```

Another way you could do it is to just change the buffered image.

Add the following method to your image panel.

```
public void loadImage(String dateiname) {
    try {
        bf = ImageIO.read(new File(dateiname));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in your action listener.

```
ip.loadNewImage("new_image.jpg");
ip.repaint();
```

You have a bunch of bad habits going on in your code though.

Such as, override paintComponent instead of paint and it should look like.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bf.getScaledInstance(300,200,1),0,0,null );
}
```

That way transparency will be handled correctly.

You shouldn't extend JFrame, you should just create a JFrame.

When you add components, you there is a layout manager involved. It's good to be aware of that and handle things accordingly. I would change your constructor to.

```
public Hauptfenster() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ip = new ImagePanel("first_image.jpg");
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    changeImage = new JButton("change image");
    buttonPanel.add(changeImage);

    changeImage.addActionListener((e) -> {
        frame.remove(ip);
        ip = new ImagePanel("new_image.jpg");
        frame.add(ip, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.repaint();
    });
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(ip, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you need more help, you'll need to actually make your example compilable. There are too many errors right now.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot and finally both methods of changing the BufferedImage or removing and adding the new instance of ImagePanel worked. My plan is to implement a kind of diashow in the JFrame. As it takes some times for the image to be scaled, does swing work asynchronously here? Although feel free the mention my bad habits in the code as I am still learining

Comment: Swing does everything on one thread, the event dispatch thread (EDT). If scaling takes a long time, you might load and scale the image on a different thread. Maybe a SwingWorker, so that when you paint you don't have to scale every time (like you're doing now.)